# How to hide product form custom field it it has null value and show if it is notnull

Tags: magento2, product, forms, modifier

I have a field named 'soldout_date' in product form. If it has null value then i don't want to show the field in the form. But if it has some value then how to show??
I am using productmodifiers.

```
public function getSoldOutDate(array $options = [])
    {
        return array_replace_recursive(
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('SoldOut Date'),
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Date::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'soldout_date',
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'sortOrder' => 10,
                            'disabled' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            $options
        );
    }
```

form field: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IJGj.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
public function getSoldOutDate(array $options = [])
{
    $product = $this->locator->getProduct();

    $disabled =  ($product->getSoldOutDate()) ? false : true;
    return array_replace_recursive(
        [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('SoldOut Date'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Date::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => 'soldout_date',
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                        'disabled' => $disabled,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        $options
    );
}
```

If your class does not have $this->locator yet, declare it by:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface $locator
    ...
)
{
    $this->locator = $locator;
}
```

Comment: If this does not work for you, please add the full content of your productmodifiers class, and I'll continue helping you.

Comment: Thank you its worked.